# How to call a server side function on a html <a> click event from inside the Iframe?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to call a onclick function of server side like below(i.e in **test.aspx.cs**)

```
protected void linkTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a=HiddenField1.value;
    Response.Write("<script>alert("+a +" is called)</script>");
}
```

And i am passing the **test.html** as **src** in **Iframe**(i.e in **test.aspx**)

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<iframe id="Iframe" src="../test.html" ></iframe>
```

My HTML control is like below and it is **inside** **test.html**

```
<a id="linkTest" runat="server" onclick="linkTest_Click">Test</a>
```

Now,I want to call a server side onClick event(`linkTest_Click`) on this `<a>` which is inside `iframe` control which is inside `test.aspx`

Comment: You can achieve that either using an ASP Update Panel in combination with script manager, or through AJAX

Comment: How exactly will i use ASP Update Panel?

Comment: Please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

Comment: so are u suggesting that i shall keep my iframe and hiddenfield inside updatepanel and then accessing the event?

Comment: do you need an iframe? There are a lot of issues with that.

Comment: yes I m loading my content through it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a server side function directly. But with some simple jQuery it is possible.

On the page containing the iframe place the following code

```
<iframe src="index.html" width="200" height="100" frameborder="1"></iframe>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeIframeCode() {
        $('#Button1').click();
    }
</script>
```

Then in the iframe put a button or whatever you want and call the function `executeIframeCode` in the parent.

```
<button onclick="parent.executeIframeCode()" type="button">
    Execute Parent Code
</button>
```

Parent code behind code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Called from Iframe!";
}
```

This only works if the iframe page is on the same domain.